# Why am I getting Incorrect argument label in call

Tags: ios, swift

Getting "Incorrect argument label in call (have 'rest:', expected 'restaurant:')" error. Here is the code. The parameter is correct and I am passing the correct type? Is this because they are class methods?

```
         class func save(restaurant: Restaurant, toCloud: Bool) -> Bool {
            var rest:RestaurantMO
            var saved:Bool = false
            if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
                rest = RestaurantMO(context: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)
                rest.name = restaurant.name
                rest.item = restaurant.item
                rest.location = restaurant.location
                rest.isVisited = restaurant.isVisited

                // Core Data Exercise - Solution
                rest.phone = restaurant.phone

                let entity =
                    NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Restaurant",
                                               in: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)!
                _ = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                             insertInto: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)

                print("Saving data to context ...")
                appDelegate.saveContext()
                saved = true

            }
            if toCloud {
                saveRecordToCloud(rest:RestaurantMO)  <--- ERROR: Incorrect argument label in call (have 'rest:', expected 'restaurant:')
            }

        }



         class func saveRecordToCloud(restaurant:RestaurantMO!) -> Void {

            // Prepare the record to save
            let record = CKRecord(recordType: "Restaurant")
            record.setValue(restaurant.name, forKey: "name")
            record.setValue(restaurant.item, forKey: "item")
            record.setValue(restaurant.location, forKey: "location")
            record.setValue(restaurant.phone, forKey: "phone")

            let imageData = restaurant.image! as Data

            // Resize the image
            let originalImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!
            let scalingFactor = (originalImage.size.width > 1024) ? 1024 / originalImage.size.width : 1.0
            let scaledImage = UIImage(data: imageData, scale: scalingFactor)!

            // Write the image to local file for temporary use
            let imageFilePath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + restaurant.name!
            let imageFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: imageFilePath)
            try? UIImageJPEGRepresentation(scaledImage, 0.8)?.write(to: imageFileURL)

            // Create image asset for upload
            let imageAsset = CKAsset(fileURL: imageFileURL)
            record.setValue(imageAsset, forKey: "image")

            // Get the Public iCloud Database
            let publicDatabase = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase

            // Save the record to iCloud
            publicDatabase.save(record, completionHandler: { (record, error) -> Void  in
                // Remove temp file
                try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: imageFileURL)
            })
        }
```

Comment: `saveRecordToCloud(restaurant: rest)`

Comment: rest is the param being passed in?

Answer (score 0):

> The parameter is correct and I am passing the correct type

No, both are wrong.

The method is declared as

```
class func saveRecordToCloud(restaurant:RestaurantMO!)
```

- The parameter label is `restaurant` rather than `rest` (stated clearly by the error message)
- The parameter type is `RestaurantMO` rather than `RestaurantMO.type` (an instance is expected)

The correct syntax is

```
saveRecordToCloud(restaurant: rest)
```

---

Note: As the parameter is non-optional remove the exclamation mark in the method declaration:

```
func saveRecordToCloud(restaurant:RestaurantMO)
```